# foreach loop running but not giving results

Tags: stata

I am having trouble running a foreach loop. The loop runs without error but gives no output.  Can someone tell me what they think might be going on?  Many thanks in advance!

Here is the code:

```
cd "O:\RESEARCH\ikhilko\Subway Big Data project"
local datafiles : dir . files  "*.txt"

foreach file in `datafiles' {
insheet using `file', 
clear
insheet using `file',
drop v9-v43
save date1, replace
}
```

UPDATE:

Interestingly, the code runs when I just type it into the command line, rather than doing it from the .do file, any idea what might be going on there?

Comment: `display` the contents of your local `datafiles` to see what's going into the loop. Surround your local with double quotes when doing this (see `help quotes`). Why do `insheet` twice? Why the `,`s at the end of lines if your not using options?

Comment: It seems like your local is empty. (You should copy exact output in your post. We don't have your pc/dir/files.)

Comment: Roberto thank you, the local looks like this: . display `datafiles'
turnstile_100724.txtturnstile_100626.txtturnstile_100703.txtturnstile_100710.txtturnstile_100717.txt

Comment: and running your command gives the following . display `"`wordx'"'
turnstile_100724.txt

Answer (score 2):

It is important to note that `local` macros are precisely that, i.e. defined and visible only locally.

Locally means within

the same interactive session

or

the same program

or

the same do file (or do file editor contents)

or

the same part of the do file (or ...) executed by selection

Locality is, it seems, biting you here. A local macro defined in one place is not visible in another. A local macro reference will evaluate to missing, i.e. an empty string, if the macro is not visible.

Comment: thanks Nick, that's what I was missing!  didnt know the logic about that but just read up and it runs exactly as you said.  much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Some code for the debugging. `display` the contents of your local `datafiles` to see what's going into the loop:

```
local datafiles : dir . files "*.txt"
display `"`datafiles'"'

local wordx : word 1 of `datafiles'
display `"`wordx'"'

foreach file in `datafiles' {
    display "`file'"
}
```

(The code does not format well in the comments section.)