# Stata: wildcard with exceptions in egen functions

Tags: function, stata

I am new to using macros, and I want to incorporate this ["Wildcard with exceptions" syntax](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2006-12/msg00911.html) into an `egen` function in Stata 12.  I would like to do something along the lines of this:

```
foreach i in E F G {
    unab all`i' : V_`i'*
    unab excl`i' : V_`i'9*
    local general`i' : list all`i' - excl`i'
} 

egen Exp_operating = rowtotal(`generalE')
egen Exp_capital = rowtotal(`generalF' `generalG')
```

In words, I want to make a variable list of `V_E*` that excludes variables `V_E9*`, and then create a variable that is equal to the sum of each variable in that list for each observation. However, I get a syntax error after executing the `egen` command.  Can someone help me figure out how to do what I want to do?

Comment: This is just to flag for future readers that the use of `egen` here is irrelevant to the OP's problem, which appears to focus entirely on misunderstanding of `local` macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some code with technique:

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example data -----

set obs 1

gen V_E1 = 1
gen V_E2 = 2
gen V_E22 = 2
gen V_E3 = 3

gen V_F1 = 3
gen V_F2 = 4
gen V_F22 = 4
gen V_F3 = 5

*----- what you seek -----

foreach i in E F {
    unab all`i' : V_`i'*
    unab excl`i' : V_`i'2*
    local general`i' : list all`i' - excl`i'
} 

* display contents of macros 
display "`generalE'"
display "`generalE' `generalF'"

* sum of V_E1 V_E3
egen Exp_operating = rowtotal(`generalE')

* sum of V_E1 V_E3 V_F1 V_F3
egen Exp_capital = rowtotal(`generalE' `generalF') 

list
```

Use `display` to check the contents of macros before passing them on to `egen`.

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, but are you not receiving a syntax error after executing the `egen` command?  I'm pretty sure that my syntax is the same as yours, but I'm getting an `invalid syntax r(198)` error whenever I execute it.  After I saw your answer, I added the `display` command into the loop to confirm that the macro did what I wanted so +1 for that.

Comment: It's not silly since I did not say it was tested code, but in fact, it is. **No error for me**. `search r(198)` gives "These errors are often, but not always, due to typographical errors. Are you sure they are the same? Did you copy/paste from the screen?

Comment: The quotes surrounding macros sometimes give problems in the sense that they appear to be the correct ones, but are not.

Comment: In fact, I now see that what you posted and what I posted is virtually the same code (after one of my last edits). Can you post the exact input/output as shown in the Stata window? What version of Stata are you using?

Comment: Yeah, I quadruple-checked my code for typos and still couldn't figure it out, so I just copied and pasted yours, and it worked fine.  Thanks!  I'm using Stata 12.

Comment: Oh, I may have figured out the problem.  Do you have to execute the entire code at once?  For example, when I executed the `foreach` loop, revised code in the `display` or `egen` command, and then executed the `display` and `egen` commands, I received the syntax error.  But when I executed the whole code at once after making revisions, no syntax error.

Comment: Yes, you must. Local macros have, well, local scope. After you run the first part of the code, the local macro is erased; thus being unavailable when you run the following part. This is something I usually fail to ask when I'm trying to diagnose, even though it has come up several times. Sorry about that.

Comment: Here is an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613915/foreach-loop-running-but-not-giving-results/21634665#21634665